# Accessing comments in RDBMS through sql query in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

Is there a way to access comments stored in RDBMS through sql query in Oracle database? I am particularly interested in comments made on stored procedures, triggers etc. I am aware of the `ALL_TAB_COMMENTS` existence, but need to gain access to comments on not only tables and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of stored procedures/packages is available through `ALL_SOURCE` (or `DBA_SOURCE`). It does not mark comments, though (which may only be part of a line, or may consist of multiple lines.)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2063.htm#i1588578

Comment: So how would implementation of such method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getFunctions%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 be possible? I mean getting `REMARKS` field. Only through using regexp to extract the comment on the output from `ALL_SOURCE`?

Comment: Yes you would parse it. The Oracle driver does only report table/view/columns (when remarksReporting=true).

Comment: I see. So when it is set to true, how can I access them?